# How do I view the size of a mount point drive on 2008R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, disk-space-utilization

The size column tells me the capacity of the drive but not the amount of disk used.

How do I determine how much data is on a mount point in 2008 R2?  Any GUI or powershell command is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
get-wmiobject Win32_volume |select Name,Capacity,Freespace
```

That'll get you a list of everything, including mount-points, and their capacities.

As for GUI, it's there just a bit hidden. When you go to properties on the mount point itself, there is a button on the first page that'll give you the disk-stats same as you would at the root of something like C:.

Comment: That works!  I'm new to PS... Is it possible to run remotely?

Comment: @makerofthings7 Certainly... add `-computername $RemoteName` to the `get-wmiobject` command to get a remote machine's listing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also take a look at this powershell script:

http://www.powershellcave.com/?p=25

It has proven to be very handy when monitoring lots of mountpoints.

#### script below

```
#############################################
#
# POWERSHELLCAVE.COM
# NAME: Mountpoint Monitoring
# Author: Caveman
# Summary: returns returnstate number that identifies state, replace with 
# any desired message you would like to have in your monitoring system.
#
# Version
# 19-02-2013   Initial version 
# 20-02-2013   Production version 1.0
#############################################

$maxmount="10"$mediummount="15"$returnStateOK=0$returnStateWarning=1$returnStateCritical=2$returnStateUnknown=3$TotalGB= @{Name="Capacity(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.Capacity/1073741824),2)}}
$FreeGB= @{Name="FreeSpace(GB)";expression={[math]::round(($_.FreeSpace /1073741824),2)}}
$FreePerc= @{Name="Free";expression={[math]::round(((($_.FreeSpace /1073741824)/($_.Capacity /1073741824)) *100),0)}}

$volumes=Get-WmiObjectwin32_volume | Where-object {$_.DriveLetter -eq$null}
$points= @($volumes | Select SystemName, Label, $TotalGB, $FreeGB, $FreePerc) 

foreach ($entryin$pionts){
    if ($entry.Free -le$maxmount){
    $message="System"+""+$entry.SystemName +""+" mountpoint "+$entry.label+""+"has"+""+$entry.Free +"%"+"  free space available"Write-Host$message
    exit $returnStateCritical
    }
    elseif ($entry.Free -le$mediummount){
    $message="System"+""+$entry.SystemName +""+" mountpoint "+$entry.label+""+"has"+""+$entry.Free +"%"+"  free space available"Write-Host$message
    exit $returnStateWarning
    }
    else { 

        Write-Host"OK"
        exit $returnStateOK
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.